# Get data type information of column in Orchard Migration file

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I have a problem with migration. Some websites on multitennancy migrated ok, some not. So, now I have to get a type of one column. Exists any way to get some information about data type of DB? Something like this:

```
public int UpdateFrom4()
{
        var dType = SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"select data_type from information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME = 'MyModule_Orchard_SettingsRecord' and COLUMN_NAME = 'SomeColumn'").Interpreter;
        if(dType != "ntext"){
        ...do some alternate of db
```

Or how to get session of nHibernate? Or direct access to DB? But I dont know the path to DB (multitennancy).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `ExecuteSQL()` method (or I believe any of the migrations commands) to get results back to code, so it is no good if you need feedback from your SQL command.

As to where the database *is*, well, it depends where you put it! If you are using multitenancy, then you can go to the `landlord | Admin | Tenants` and view the details for the tenant you setup. The connection method / string will be listed there. If the mode is SQL Server CE, then the database will be in the `App_Data/Sites/{nameoftenant}` folder, but you will need a tool to open it. The easiest if you use Visual Studio is [SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1). With any other connection string, SQL Server Management Studio is the way to go.From there, it is just using SQL as normal

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, Its not so good way to needing results in migration method. But something was wrong in migration and now I have three options. 1) Open it manually as you write, but in hundreds tenants. 2) Write app for fixing databases. 3) Get some information in migration method and make changes only in DB where its necessary. So, exist any possibility to get some information about DB in migration methods?

Comment: It's still .NET code - you can still open a SQLConnection and do your own thing. You just need to be *really* sure what you are doing (as I'm sure this is "unsupported"). For example if you intend to delete a table added by a feature for a widget, you'd need to guarantee that there were no instances of the widget added to layers. Extreme "dry run" testing, and backups of your databases before execution for real is a must. You need to ensure that at the end of the correction process, that the migrations version for the feature is the same on all tenants (assuming they are all now "correct")

Comment: You are absolutely true that testing is needed. And I did. There was no big deal, only extend text data type of one column. Nothing happends. And you are sure, that its still .NET code, but as I wrote in my question, I dont know in migration method anything about connectionstring of concrete database.